# jib: Unauthorized but docker login works

Tags: maven, jib

I'm running in an issue with maven jib.

I'm able to login on my private registry:

```
$ docker login 
  -p <password>
  -u <user>
  docker-registry-default.si-origin-cluster.t-systems.es
Login Succeeded
```

With maven I'm getting:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.google.cloud.tools:jib-maven-plugin:2.5.0:build (default-cli) on project connector: Build image failed, perhaps you should make sure your credentials for 'docker-registry-default.si-origin-cluster.t-systems.es/arxius/connector' are set up correctly. See https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/blob/master/docs/faq.md#what-should-i-do-when-the-registry-responds-with-unauthorized for help: Unauthorized for docker-registry-default.si-origin-cluster.t-systems.es/arxius/connector: 401 Unauthorized

My mvn command is:

```
$ mvn clean package
  jib:build -Dimage=docker-registry-default.si-origin-cluster.t-systems.es/arxius/connector
  -Djib.to.auth.username=<user>
  -Djib.to.auth.password=<password>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Jib can get credentials for the registry from `~/.docker/config.json` after you do `docker login`. Can you try without `-Djib.to.auth.username|password`? And are you behind a proxy? What is the registry implementation? Sonatype Nexus?

Answer (score -1):

Please note that Jib is not complaining about authentication (login) but authorization. You may login into a registry and pull an image from it but may not push an image to it, depending on your permissions.

Check by pushing any image with "docker image push" if you are authorized to push an image to that registry.